# ASP.NET: Populating a dropdown with a datavalue field different from the datatext field

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to populate a drop-down list with data returned by a SQL Server stored procedure but make it so that the data value text field is one field returned by the stored procedure and the data value field is another value returned by the stored procedure (the stored procedure returns a field called 'Parent Name' and another field called 'Parent ID'). The code behind is VB and I will post it below:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim s_SQL_Database_Connection As SqlConnection

    Dim s_Connection_String As String = Session("Connection_String")

    Dim s_SQL_Command As SqlCommand

    Dim s_Record_Set As SqlDataReader

    s_SQL_Database_Connection = New SqlConnection(s_Connection_String)

    s_SQL_Database_Connection.Open()

    s_SQL_Command = New SqlCommand("EXEC Krandor.MattA.__Parent_List", s_SQL_Database_Connection)

    s_Record_Set = s_SQL_Command.ExecuteReader()

    Dim parent_name As String
    Dim parent_id As Integer

    While s_Record_Set.Read
        parent_name = s_Record_Set.Item("Parent Name")
        Me.cbo_parent.Items.Add(New ListItem(parent_name))
    End While

    s_Record_Set.Close()

    s_SQL_Database_Connection.Close()

End Sub


Public ReadOnly Property parent_id() As String
    Get
        Dim s_parent As String

        s_parent = cbo_parent.DataValueField

        Return s_parent
    End Get
End Property
```

Basically, in the while loop, I want to set 'Parent Name' to the text field for each drop-down item and 'Parent ID' equal to the value field for each drop-down item. Any help will be greatly appreciated and I apologize if this question has been asked already (I searched but could not find anything that I could apply to my situation).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `Parent ID` field value as a second parameter to ListItem constructor:

```
 While s_Record_Set.Read
        parent_name = s_Record_Set.Item("Parent Name")
        Me.cbo_parent.Items.Add(New ListItem(parent_name, s_Record_Set.Item("Parent ID")))
    End While
```